# Create and Add new Variable to a CheckedListBox

Tags: arrays, winforms, powershell

I want to automate this code below and make it dynamic, so when I click on the button **Add** it should create a `$template(x)` and it should be added to the `$TemplateArray`.

*(The `$menulist` is a `CheckedListBox` and it shows file names)*

but

For now I have `$template1`, `$template2` and if i want another one I have to type it in the code manually but I want this to be done by the **Add** button.

```
$template1 = Split-Path C:\Users\$Env:USERNAME\Documents\test.txt -Leaf -Resolve
$template2 = Split-Path C:\Users\$Env:USERNAME\Documents\test2.txt -Leaf -Resolve
$TemplateArray = $template1,$template2;
$menulist.Items.AddRange($TemplateArray)



$button_add_OnClick = {
    #TODO: Place custom script here
}
```

Also is it possible after when I click on **Add** that it asks me for the file location and that is going to be formatted something like this because I want only show the file name in the `CheckedListBox` but I also want to be able to open the file with another button ( but *Open* button is not part of this question)

```
Split-Path C:\Users\$Env:USERNAME\Documents\test.txt -Leaf -Resolve
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking a user to select a file from a form is pretty easy - just use the [`OpenFileDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
$AddButton.add_Click({
    # Create Dialog
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog

    # Configure its behavior to your liking
    $OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = $PWD
    $OpenFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt"

    # Launch it and wait for user to select file
    if($OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
    {
        # Add the path of the selected file to the CheckedListBox Items
        $menulist.Items.Add($OpenFileDialog.FileName)

        # Add to the Templates array as well
        $TemplateArray += $OpenFileDialog.FileName
    }
})
```

---

You mention that you'll need the full path of the file later, but you're only interested in showing the Name of the file to the user.

You can accomplish this by adding proper [`FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) objects (same type that Get-Item and Get-ChildItem returns for files) to the list, rather than just strings:

```
$template1 = Get-Item C:\Users\$Env:USERNAME\Documents\test.txt
$template2 = Get-Item C:\Users\$Env:USERNAME\Documents\test2.txt
$TemplateArray = $template1,$template2

$AddButton.add_Click({
# ...
# Same as before
# ...

    if($OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
    {
        $TargetFile = Get-Item $OpenFileDialog.FileName
        # Add the selected file to the CheckedListBox Items
        $menulist.Items.Add($TargetFile)

        # Add to the Templates array as well
        $TemplateArray += $TargetFile
    }
})
```

And then finally set the [`DisplayMember` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9dzztb(v=vs.110).aspx) of your CheckedListBox to make sure it displays the Name of the file:

```
$menulist.DisplayMember = "Name"
```

So in the GUI, it looks like you just have a list of strings, but when you retrieve `SelectedItems` it's a full-fledged `FileInfo` object:

```
PS> $menulist.SelectedItems[0].FullName
C:\Users\CodeBusta\Documents\test.txt
```